# Prevent Jsoup's HTML Parser from converting single tags to self-closing tags

Tags: jsoup

Is there any way to prevent Jsoup's HTML parser from converting single tags (most specifically `<br>` tags), into self-closing tags?

`<br>` tags are valid HTML5 elements, but Jsoup keeps converting them to `<br />`.

I have an example setup at the link below:

http://try.jsoup.org/~zCiL6-fonHhQaGaApm2tORtfoo0

I need to figure out how to disable this behavior, but I haven't been able to figure out how to do it after pouring through the docs and examples. Perhaps it isn't an option yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading through the code, it appears that the Jsoup authors have fixed the issue in this [commit](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/commit/6c4f16f233cdfd7aedef33374609e9aa4ede255c).

Comment: Can you tell me in which version this issue is fixed ?